# What regular expression not work in android

Tags: android, regex

Hi i want a regular expression for a-z A-Z 0_9آ-ی( Persian)

```
String regex ="^(?:([a-z A-Z 0-9])||([آ-ی]))+$";
```

i do not want allow special characters like !@#$%^&*()?><+- .

and my commllet code is :

```
public  int check_first_last_name(String name){
  String regex ="^(?:([a-zA-Z0-9])||([آ-ی]))+$";
 Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( regex ).matcher(name);
 if (!matcher.find( )){
     return 2;
 }
 return 1;
}
```

Comment: `^(?:([a-zA-Z0-9])|([آ-ی]))+$` , `||` should be `|` and for clarity add your valid cases and invalid cases and description about what exactly you want

Comment: I edit and fix my mistakes. take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

this regex accept every words in English ,Persian and Arabic if you want allow space change end of regex to "...0-9 "

```
if(name.matches("^([\\u0600-\\u06FF\\uFB8A\\u067E\\u0686\\u06AFa-zA-Z0-9])+$")){
//do what you want
}
```

please check in code you must have 2 backslash before every unicode not 4!

and if you want accept all tabs newline and space you can use this regex:

```
"^([\\u0600-\\u06FF\\uFB8A\\u067E\\u0686\\u06AFa-zA-Z0-9]+\\s?)+$"
```